# Probability mass function of drawing balls from an urn with two kinds of balls

Tags: probability-theory

The problem is : Suppose you have an urn with $r \in \mathbb{N}$ many red balls and $b \in \mathbb{N}$ many black balls. All balls of same colour look identical. Suppose you sample uniformly from this urn with replacement. Let N be the minimum number of balls needed to see balls of all colours. Find the pmf of $N$.

Let $X$ be the random variable of minimum number of balls needed to see balls of all colours. Then $p_X(x)=P(X = x)$. Here, we have $x-1$ many balls of same colour appearing before the $x^{\text{th}}$ ball is of different colour. If the first $x-1$ balls are of colour red, then there are $r^{n-1}$ many ways of it happening multiplied by $b$ ways of the $x^{\text{th}}$ ball being blue. Similarly, if the first $x-1$ balls are blue and the last ball is red, total number of ways are $b^{n-1}r$. So $p_X(x) = P[X=x] = \dfrac{r^{n-1}b+b^{n-1}r}{(r+b)^n}$. It can be seen that $$\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{r^{n-1}b+b^{n-1}r}{(r+b)^n} = \dfrac{r}{r+b} + \dfrac{b}{b+r} = 1$$ so it is a valid pmf.

Is this solution correct? (Please help me here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n\geq 0$ and note that
$$\begin{aligned}P(N>n) 
&= P(\text{all balls all up to } n \text{ are of the same color})
\\&= P(\text{all balls all up to } n \text{ are red}) + P(\text{all balls all up to } n \text{ are blue})
\\&= \left(\frac{r}{r+b}\right)^n + \left(\frac{b}{r+b}\right)^n.
\end{aligned}$$

As a consequence, for $n\geq 1$, $$P(N=n) = P(N>n-1) -  P(N>n)= \ldots = \frac{r^{n-1}b+rb^{n-1}}{(r+b)^n}.$$

This is is the same as what you've found.